# SignatureDoesNotMatch when calling PutObject with Django, Django-Storage, AWS S3, boto3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku

I created a Django App and host it on Heroku where I specified all setting vars such as Access Key ID (see Settings file).

```py
# Amazon S3 Settings
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= config("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID= config("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME= config("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN=f"{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com" # this is the default storage class to generate url for storage 
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL="public-read"
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    "CacheControl": "max-age=86400"
}
AWS_LOCATION= "static"  #A path prefix that will be prepended to all uploads
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "eu-west-1"
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH=False
AWS_HEADERS={
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
}
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE= "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE= "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage"
STATIC_URL= f"https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/static/"
MEDIA_URL= f"https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/media/"

# Heroku Logging
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
# Assets Management
ASSETS_ROOT = os.getenv('ASSETS_ROOT', f"https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/static/assets")
```

> Relevant requirements:
>
> ```
> django-storages==1.12.3    
> boto3==1.26.31
> ```

Anyone any ideas on how to solve this?

I tried the IAM user with full access, only S3 Full access, the Access Keys of the global account and I just keep geeting the error: **"botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when cagettinghe the PutObject operation:  The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."** when trying to upload something to S3. The website then outputs:

> ```
> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an unexpected internal server error
>
> (generated by the waitress)
> ```

The logger I added to the settings file on Django is not helpful at all as it just shows me a SignatureDoesNotMatch error.

I tried Access Keys with + and without as this might be the source of the error. I couldn't find any best practices on how to insert the keys to the Heroku settings but a lot of ppl reporting errors when copying the keys from the AWS website. I checked it with the CSV file and the website output.

I tried to add the images through the admin page in case my HTML page is faulty. Same error. The

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1277.0.min.js"></script>
```

the line is added to the HTML page as well. And I save it through

```
form.save()
```

on my HTML page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't actually shown the code that throws the `botocore.exceptions.ClientError` exception but code *around* the SDK - can you please show the code that is throwing that error?

Comment: For the https://websiteurl/admin page, I do not need to add any code expect for adding my form model to the admin page e.g. "admin.site.register(Model)"  and get the same error when I enter and save some data.

Comment: Ah okay. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344) and add your 'setting files' as code within the question.

Comment: What is the request going to the server? Is it post request or put request?

Comment: its a post request.